# Problem with feature "class" as a column in data frame

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe ("train") with one feature "class".

train["class"].dtype is working fine, but when i am using train.class.dtype, it is giving an error.

Why is this happening only when the feature name is lowercase "class"?

train.Class.dtype is working perfectly because of uppercase c in "Class".

Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: `class` is a [keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).  You can't use it as an identifier.

Comment: Which is unfortunate, as allowing `train.class` wouldn't cause any syntactic ambiguity (Ruby, for instance, allows this sort of thing, even for reserved words).